# UITableView header for section only appears when scrolling down

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios5

I have some weird behavior on the iPad that I am not getting on the iPhone.

I have a Grouped table view that has sections and headers for the sections, the problem is that on the iPad the top most section's header is not displayed, when scrolling down the table the sections header appears for a short while just before going of screen.

Before scrolling

[http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg525/scaled.php?server=525&filename=screenshot2012051410074.png&res=landing http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg525/scaled.php?server=525&filename=screenshot2012051410074.png&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg525/scaled.php?server=525&filename=screenshot2012051410074.png&res=landing)

After scrolling

[http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg59/scaled.php?server=59&filename=screenshot2012051410074.png&res=landing http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg59/scaled.php?server=59&filename=screenshot2012051410074.png&res=landing](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg59/scaled.php?server=59&filename=screenshot2012051410074.png&res=landing)

The code for creating the headers of the sections:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil || [sectionTitle isEqualToString:@""]) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init] ;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(12, 0, 300, 30);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    label.text = sectionTitle;

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header"];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 44)];
    imgView.image = img;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 44)];

    [view addSubview:imgView];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int aSection = [[self.sectionsToDisplay objectAtIndex:section] integerValue];
    return [self.groupHeadings objectAtIndex:aSection];
}
```

My TableView's code:

```
tableViewResult = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:mainView.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

tableViewResult.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[mainView addSubview:tableViewResult];
```

I set the delegate and datasource in another method as I first do a web request before loading any data into the table, ie when the web request is done I do:

```
tableViewResult.delegate = self;
tableViewResult.dataSource = self;
[tableViewResult reloadData];
```

Everything works as expected except for the header of the top most section, and only on the iPad.

Any ideas what can cause this behavior?

Comment: How do you create the TableView, From Interface Builder or code?. What is the height of the header?. Can you upload a screenshot?.

Comment: I build it from code, will upload screenshots.

Comment: did you write method for hieght of section.

Comment: @MangeshVyas adding the method to specify a height for the section header shows the header, but it has a lot of extra padding.

Comment: In your case, I think your scrollview placing doesn't have the space needed for the navigation bar. Place your scrollview 44 pixels below and see.

Comment: @deamonsarea nope, found the real problem though, I wasn't returning nil for empty strings

Comment: Didn't think it was a case with the string. How could you? :)

Comment: What size you have for section ? 44 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed the issue was changing this function to:

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int aSection = [[self.sectionsToDisplay objectAtIndex:section] integerValue];
    if([[self.groupHeadings objectAtIndex:aSection] isEqualToString:@""])
        return nil;
    return [self.groupHeadings objectAtIndex:aSection];
}
```